# How would I be able to store values like '0x97' in an array in Swift?

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm trying to figure out how to implement this ObjC code in swift:

```
const unsigned char information[] = {0x95, 0x5f, 0x2e};
```

I have trying doing this: `let information = [0x95, 0x5f, 0x2e]` but when I use break points and debug the program it says that the array information has no values in it. Would someone be able to help me figure this out?

Thank you!

Comment: Hay billy i can see this in while testing https://www.dropbox.com/s/4qru9khdrkgw50l/Screen%20Shot%202014-12-11%20at%2011.12.27%20am.png?dl=0

Comment: I tried your solution in playground and it works fine: https://www.dropbox.com/s/brwxbp3p0plip84/Screenshot%202014-12-11%2008.44.23.png?dl=0

Comment: is this what you want ?

Comment: @billy me and kirill confirm that there is no problem in your code so please give us more detail.

Comment: `0x95` just just a way of representing a number (`149` in base-10) as hexadecimal. There is nothing special about it.

Comment: the values of `const unsigned char information[] = {0x95, 0x5f, 0x2e};` are different from `let information = [0x95,0x5f,0x2e]`. I need to include these byte values in my swift project because I use it to connect to a server that lets me do voice to text. The ObjC code is from the example program that uses the voice to text and I'm trying to convert it to swift (because my whole project was already done in swift). When I check the values of that array in objc, they're different from `let information = []` in swift. In Swift it shows integers while in Objc it shows as char.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jeff is correct.

You cannot use the `information[]` syntax anymore.

```
arrayName:[Type] = [member1, member2, etc]
```

is the correct way to initialize an array.

Actually, to be more complete with this answer:

```
internal let arrayName:[Type] = [member1, member2, etc]
```

if you will not be modifying the array.

```
internal var arrayName:[Type] = [member1, member2, etc]
```

if you will be modifying the array later.

I understand that internal is the default access, but I'm finding with Swift that I need to be careful about how Swift infers types; I now always specify a type in a variable declaration and this care just carries over to explicitly declaring the access.

Answer (score 0):

```
let information: [CUnsignedChar] = [0x95, 0x5f, 0x2e]
println(information) // output [149, 95, 46]
```